# MYSQL, SELECT syntax problem, how do I select rows of a table based on a requirement in another table

Tags: mysql

I have solved 90% of this problem except for one command and am having trouble on the syntax. I have a Customer table and a Rep table, and I want to select customers who:

1. are closest to a lat lng point (which I have figured out)
2. exist within a Rep's boundry (Polygon),

***What am I doing wrong here?***

```
    SELECT 
      id,
      name,
      contact,   
      address,
      location, 
      X(location) AS "longitude", 
      Y(location) AS "latitude", 
      ( 
      GLength( 
          LineStringFromWKB( 
            LineString( 
              location, 
              GeomFromText('POINT(-41.29463639999999 174.7748175)') 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
      AS distance 

    FROM Customers as Customer

    WHERE 
      location IS NOT NULL

    AND
      Customer.id NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId from SalesRepCustomer WHERE SalesRepId = 15)

    --- CODE BELOW I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH:
    AND 
      Customer.location IN (
        SELECT * from SalesReps as SalesRep
            WHERE ST_CONTAINS(SalesRep.bounds, location)
            AND SalesRep.id = 15
        )
    --- CODE ABOVE I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH:

    ORDER BY distance ASC

    LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, use `exists` instead of `IN`
second, use `subquery` to order by your `distance`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
      id,
      name,
      contact,   
      address,
      location, 
      X(location) AS "longitude", 
      Y(location) AS "latitude", 
      ( 
      GLength( 
          LineStringFromWKB( 
            LineString( 
              location, 
              GeomFromText('POINT(-41.29463639999999 174.7748175)') 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
      AS distance 

    FROM Customers as Customer
    WHERE 
      location IS NOT NULL
    AND
      Customer.id NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId from SalesRepCustomer WHERE SalesRepId = 15)
    AND 
      Customer.location exists (
        SELECT *1 from SalesReps as SalesRep
            WHERE ST_CONTAINS(SalesRep.bounds, location)
            AND SalesRep.id = 15
        )
) t1
ORDER BY t1.distance ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: @zoku, if you accept this answer, don't forget to click the check sign under the down arrow button.